# Case class extending trait not working with copy

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

I try

```
trait Foo[A] {
  def copy(int: Int): A
}

case class Bar(int: Int) extends Foo[Bar]
```

but I get

> error: class Bar needs to be abstract, since method copy in trait Foo of type (int: Int)this.Bar is not defined

Since `Bar` is a case class, it automatically defines a `copy` method with exactly this signature.

Why doesn't the `Foo` class satisfy the interface defined by the trait `Bar`?

Comment: The case class won't implement copy if it's inherited, even if abstract. There is a duplicate of this somewhere.

Comment: @m-z, found it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937020/define-copy-method-in-trait-for-case-class That is itself marked as a duplicate, IMO incorrectly.

Answer (score 5):

I am quoting the [Scala's specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes):

> A method named copy is implicitly added to every case class **unless the class already has a member (directly defined or inherited) with that name**, or the class has a repeated parameter.